# How to prevent: "File does not exist" being logged in error_log for .htaccess ErrorDocuments?

Tags: php, linux, apache

At the moment we are using a .htaccess rule for user avatars, if they have not uploaded an avatar then a 404 occurs and shows a default avatar image.

However this happens thousands of times a day and the `error_log` is pretty much constantly being written to.

The .htaccess rule is in the `/avatar/` directory which only consists of the image files.

**PHP image code**

```
<img src="/avatar/<?=$userId?>.png" />
```

**.htaccess code used in the images directory**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /unknown.gif
```

Is there any other fast way I could do this to stop the 404 error occuring or mabye even being logged?

Would a `php.ini` file in the `/avatar/` directory that turned off error reporting work?

Comment: You should avoid generating 404's completely because it is slowing down your page load. Just check if there is an uploaded image for that user when generating the html content and put the `unknown.gif` in your <img>'s src attribute directly.

Comment: Did you consider altering your code so that it does not display a non-existent URL in the first place? You could save a tiny bit of bandwidth and few unnecessary HTTP requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Only display the image, if the image exists.

```
<?php

if(file_exists("/avatar/" . $userId . ".png")) {
    print('<img src="/avatar/' . $userId . '.png" />');
}
else {
    print('<img src="/avatar/unknown.gif" />');
}

?>
```